# How to close window with figure?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have this code in matlab. How to close window with figure? I use this code, but it doesn't work, why?

```
plot(fig1);%Show chart
hold on;
if button == 1
    close(fig1);
    delete(fig1);
    break;
end;
```

---

Ok, I changed the code. But it doesn't work. Why?

```
fig1 = plot(fig0);
hold on;
if button == 1
    close(fig1);
    break;
end;
```

Comment: Just use `close(gcf)`. This closes the figure that has currently the focus.

Answer (score 1):

`close` command should work.

For instance:

```
   fig1 = figure();
   close(fig1);
```

The mistake is probably somewhere else:

1. `fig1` is not a figure handle.
2. `button`  is not equal to 1

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing `plot` with `figure`; the latter is for opening a figure, the first is to actually draw something on a figure.

```
fig_handle = figure;
plot(1:10);
if button==1
    close(fig_handle);
    delete(fig_handle);
    break;
end
```

But this is likely not going to work, it seems as you want to press a button and then close the previously opened figure. Matlab code is run sequentially, so here the variable `button` is immediately checked after opening the figure. I think you're looking for a function callback linked to a button.

Answer (score 0):

You plot the data, which is in fig1. You can not close the data, you need to close the figure

```
f=figure;
plot(1:10); % example
close(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you need to use a property on the figure itself.  I've had the exact same problem before, but your code looks a little suspect.

First, figure out what you have in each variable:

```
disp(class(fig1))
disp(ishandle(fig1))
disp(class(fig0))
disp(ishandle(fig0))
```

If `fig0` is a handle, then you can't call `plot(fig0)` as far as I know.  If `fig0` is an array of data, then you're golden.

As an aside, when you call `close()` that calls the figure `CloseRequestFcn` which can be set by another piece of code.  You may want to try `close force` if all your variables check out OK.  By the way, I'm not sure what all the down votes are for, but you may want to explain a little more background.  It's fine by me, but I guess not everyone is as forgiving. :-)